# Como "sincronizar" uma branch com master antes de trabalhar nela?

Tags: git, projeto-de-software, gerenciamento-de-projetos, branch

Eu estou com a seguinte situação: tenho um repositório Git, e em um certo momento criei uma branch a partir de master. Não fiz muita coisa, nessa branch na epoca, e aí eu avancei a branch master por vários commits, sendo que o código mudou muito.

Agora eu precisava retomar o trabalho nessa branch e completá-lo, só que ficou complicado, porque a branch está realmente muito atrasada. Nisso tem dois problemas:

1. Fica difícil implementar lá atrás quando o código era de um jeito, se agora mudou muita coisa.
2. Mesmo que eu implementasse o que eu queria com base naquele código antigo, depois para combinar com o que está na branch master eu nem tenho ideia como seria, porque afinal iriam ser códigos bastante distintos.

A única solução que eu pensei foi encontrar um jeito de pegar essa branch e avançar ela para estar igual a branch master e refazer o trabalho dela. Mas também não me parece perfeito, porque afinal eu iria perder o que já tinha começado nessa branch.

Nesse sentido como eu resolvo isso? Como eu consigo voltar a trabalhar nessa branch se eu avancei muito a branch master e agora o código está muito diferente?

Comment: Não é uma questão adequadamente classificada como **projeto-de-software** (*software design*). Remover esta marca facilitará a localização de questões.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O mais comum é:

- Crie outro branch a partir do MASTER atualizado;
- Faça o `git merge` com o teu branch que quer continuar;

Assim, você vê se há algum conflito, verifica o código com as mudanças e tem um branch atualizado.

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro, salva sua branch (em caso de qualquer problema) durante o seguinte:

```
git branch <branch_save> <branch>
```

Tenta trocar de rais da branch:

```
git rebase master <branch>
# OU
# Se você quiser trocar ordem dos commits ou apagar alguns:
git rebase -i master <branch>
```

O rais da branch sera master.
Se tem conflitos, resolva-os e `rebase --continue`.

No fim, tera seu trabalho atualizado com master: a rais da branch sera master e o trabalho sera adaptado.

Para restaurar a situação initial em caso de problema:

```
git rebase --abort # Se rebase em curso
git checkout <branch>
git reset --hard <branch_save>
```

Se você está satisfeito do resultado: apaga a salvaguarda:

```
git branch -D <branch_save>
```